# Flask-WTF model_form, Sqlalchemy, and foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm trying to take my model and generate forms using wtform's model_form for sqlalchemy.  I would like the fields with a foreign key constraint to be a select list of all the items in that table.

So far I can either get nothing or a simple text input for the literal foreign key, and I'm a little lost.

OK, so I have a relatively simple data model here.  For this I can reduce it down to where I have types of hardware, and their support statuses.  I want to be able to add support statuses in the future, and provide more useful descriptions for them.

```
from . import db
class Status(db.Model):
    """Support status"""
    __tablename__ = 'status'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

class Hardware(db.Model):
    """Hardware"""
    __tablename__ = 'hardware'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    status = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('status.id'))
    ...
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

Groovy.

Now my view looks like so:

```
from flask import render_template, request, flash, redirect, url_for
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form
from . import db, app
import models
...
@app.route('/edit/status/', defaults={'id': None}, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/edit/status/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_hardware(id=None):
    HardwareForm = model_form(models.Hardware, base_class=Form,
            db_session=db.session, exclude_fk=False)
    if id == None:
        model = models.Hardware()
    else:
        model = models.Hardware.query.get(id)
    form = HardwareForm(request.form, model)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(model)
        db.session.add(model)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("yay!")
    return render_template('forms.html', form=form)
```

So I've obviously tried the exclude_fk maneuver, but that just gives me a text field for an integer.

I feel like I need to be telling something to use the name field from Status, although I guess that could be derived from the **repr** method.

Do I need to drop the exclude_fk and manually add a QuerySelectField to the form?  Is there something I should pass in field_args?  Am I doing something dumb?

I'd like to do as little manual intervention as possible here, and I feel like this is a fairly textbook scenario.

Answer (score 0):

the `Hardware.status` column should be named `Hardware.status_id` and you should add a column to `Hardware` that will represent the relationship to the status table:

```
status = db.relationship('Status',backref='hardware',lazy='dynamic')
```

that should get you a model_form with a select for status